# Xcode CarPlay Simulator will say "CarPlay Not Available"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I currently have Xcode 12.4 installed.

I launch my iOS simulator (iPhone 12) and open CarPlay by I/O > External Display > CarPlay.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLBz0.png)

I keep getting "CarPlay Not Available. To use CarPlay, enable Siri..." for some reason.

I tried reinstalling Xcode and Simulator, but they won't help. On my other computer, it works just fine.

What should I do?

Comment: Tell us what you have done besides Enabling CarPlay under I/0.

Comment: After doing clean install, I launched the simulator and opened CarPlay and that is it. It just won't open the Home Screen of CarPlay.